# PHP - Convert date format from YY/MM/DD to yyyy-mm-dd

Tags: php, date, strtotime

i've a device that give me file logs with date format like this: 16/11/07 (today date) but when i'm trying to convert it with date() and strtotime, doesn't work and give me 1970-01-01.

```
 $row2 = "16/11/07;11:49:00"; 
 $par = explode(";",$row2); 
 $date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($par[0]));
```

Do you have some ideas?

I don't want to create a script with "20" in front of that date, because is not well formed coded.

Thank you

Comment: show your code.

Comment: $row2 = "16/11/07;11:49:00";
$par = explode(";",$row2);

$date = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($par[0]));

Comment: @maures include what u did on the question

Comment: You should use a `DateTime` object, or use `strtotime` on your variable but with using dashes (`16-11-07`) instead of slashes (`16/11/07`).

Comment: @maures : check this : https://eval.in/673304

Answer (score 1):

Use DateTime object.

```
try{
   $date = DateTime::createFromFormat('y/m/d',$my_date);
   $req_date = $date->format('Y-m-d');
   echo "Req Date : ".$req_date;
} catch (Exception $e) {
   echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Comment: change your createFromFormat  d/m/y to y/m/d.

Comment: ........done mate.  :-)